# Can't push buttons to bottom of page in CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

Been awhile since I played with Flexbox. I'm trying to push the buttons to the bottom of the page. Does the parent container always have to have a size to do that? That seems to be the only way I can get the result I want, but then I have to constantly resize based on what else is on the page. What else am I doing wrong?

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h2>My lists</h2>
<div class="all">
  <div class="top"><button>Top</button></div>
  <div class="middle"><button>Midde</button></div>
  <div class="bottom"><button>Bottom</button></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Basically, it is taking up the whole page, but not the whole viewport. A page is only as big as its content until you tell it otherwise. Inspect your snippet with the broser tools and you'll see the `body` and `html` is only as big as the content. This is effectively the page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `justify-content: flex-end;` try to use `justify-content: space-between;`so that each element will be spread.

Also you need to set a `min-height` in the `.alt` class or the container in order to see the `space-between` in action.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question, you need to define a height from the area you want to align the elements.

###### Wrap your container

You need to define your parent container as
to make the elements inside don't overflow the box itself. For that use:
`flex-wrap: wrap`

###### Make the elements inside your container use the full width

By default flex will shrink the elements. to remove the defaults and use 100% of the width, use
`flex: 0 0 100%`

###### Make your elements align itself

This is the key for your question. the elements needs to be aligned not with the other boxes, they have to align themselves. For that you must use `align-self: flex-start`, `align-self: center` or `align-self: flex-end`

#### Minimal Example

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* This is going to make full width the divs inside .all */
.all div {
 flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.top {
  align-self: flex-start; 
}

.middle {
  align-self: center;
}

.bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
    <div class="top"><button>Top</button></div>
    <div class="middle"><button>Middle</button></div>
    <div class="bottom"><button>Bottom</button></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't fix the height to 100vh. Use `min-height` instead

Comment: Yes, It makes sense if somebody is going to copy it as is, that would make it more reusable. Already Edited